# Matplotlib: plot string on y axis

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting two lists on the Y and X axis:

Y-list

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

X-list

```
2015-07-08 00:00:00
2018-02-05 00:00:00
2018-02-05 00:00:00
2018-03-08 00:00:00
2018-03-08 00:00:00
2019-07-30 00:00:00
2019-07-30 00:00:00
2019-11-18 15:00:00
```

In the final graph I would like to display a time-hisotry. Do you know how I can replace the single Y-values with names/strings (Generator1, Generator2, Generator3). See picture.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use yticks for this 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html

for example

```
yticks(np.arange(5), ('Generator1', 'Generator2', 'Generator3', '4', '5'))
```